# Unable to change display layout

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to swap around the relative location of my external monitor with my laptops internal monitor as the external monitor is on my left but appears as the display on the right however when trying to change this I am logged out of my account and the change doesn't complete, it worked when the Nvidia GPU was disabled and the intel iGPU used in it's place but was reverted when the Nvidia GPU was re-enabled.
i7-4500u, GT 750m
Ubuntu 15.10, linux 4.2.0-17, Nvida-352

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
My setup is intel(internal video) + nvidia gtx860(external + primary video) and 2 monitor(internal + external).

Workaround is to remove the file "~/.config/monitors.xml" in terminal execute command:

```
rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

Reconfigure you monitor setup after reboot/relogin, configuration file will recreated.

May be it would be helpful.

But, after secondary reboot/relogin problem will returned....